# How do I stop Atom from getting rid of all the empty space at the bottom when I save?

Tags: atom-editor

I deliberately add empty lines underneath what I have already written, in order to make the text a little bit higher. The problem is that whenever I save the Atom editor gets rid of all the empty space underneath and I have to press return to make those empty line again. Is there a way to stop the Atom editor from doing this?

Comment: No, it's different, because I want the extra lines when I press return. I press return 5 times and I have 5 lines of empty space, but when I save it becomes only 1 line of empty space.

Comment: Therefore it is not different. If you uncheck the "Remove Trailing Whitespace" setting, the trailing whitespaces wont be removed.

Comment: Sorry you are right. By disabling that option I was able to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Is the point of this practice that you want to be able to scroll the window past the end of the file and have some space to type in the bottom? You don't really need to do that this way. There's a simpler way to do it - in the Editor preferences, check the `Scroll Past End` option, and it will let you keep scrolling instead of stopping the window at the end of the file.

Comment: Yes, that was the point. Thanks Dan, that works too.